# What is preventing the context menu from showing?

Tags: ms-access, ribbonx

I have an Access database with the following ribbon XML:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" loadImage="LoadImages">
    <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
        <contextualTabs>
            <tabSet idMso="TabSetFormReportExtensibility">
                <tab id="tabContextual" label="My Contextual Tab">
                    <group id="contextualGroup" label="My Group">
                        <labelControl id="myLabels" label="Sample"/>
                        <button id="btnDemo" size="large" label="Demo"/>
                    </group>
                </tab>
            </tabSet>
        </contextualTabs>   
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

My understanding is that this particular ContextTab will show when a form is opened but I cannot get any ContextTabs to show when I open any form at all.

Is my understanding wrong or is there an error in the XML?

Also, should this code indeed show a ContextTab when a form is opened, how would you show a different context menu for a different form?  As I see it, the XML above will open that ContextTab when any form is opened and that appears to be driven by the ribbon so how does the ribbon decide which ContextTab to open for which form (should there be more than one ContextTab defined!!).

Thanks

Comment: Exactly how do you invoke that XML code - Options>Current Database>Default Ribbon or VBA or macro? Is that XML in a USysRibbons table? Forms and reports have a RibbonName property.

Comment: I tested the XML by adding in USysRibbons table, reopen db and set a form RibbonName property. It invokes the code. The ribbon displays a new tab named "My Contextual Tab" with the form name above, there is one group named "My Group", label "Sample", button "Demo". Button doesn't do anything because there is no Action method associated with it. Why would you expect this ribbon to show anything different for different forms?

Comment: Have you seen this website https://www.avenius.de/en/

Comment: @June7 with reference to `Why would you expect this ribbon to show anything different for different forms?` I would see this as am important point as you would expect different forms to be able to display different ContextualTabs as each form does a different task and therefore expect different buttons and layout etc.

Comment: Then I think you have to build different ribbons. Didn't answer my first question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that your custom ribbon UI is loaded by the host application. Try to set a breakpoint in any callback and see whether it is triggered or not.

Second, make sure you don't get any UI errors. By default, if a add-in attempts to manipulate the Microsoft Office user interface (UI) and fails, no error message is displayed. However, you can configure Microsoft Office applications to display messages for errors that relate to the UI. You can use these messages to help determine why a custom ribbon does not appear, or why a ribbon appears but no controls appear. Read more about that in the [How to: Show Add-in user interface errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-show-add-in-user-interface-errors?view=vs-2022) article.

Comment: I've ensured the ribbon is loaded and have set two callback functions - one on ribbon load and the other on button press.  The ribbon load call back fires as expected when the DB is opened.  The button one wont as there is no button because the ribbon doesn't display when a form is opened!!
I have Show Add-In User Interface Errors enabled and there are none so looks like the XML is ok even though it doesn't work correctly...